# Distinct Value after aggregation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am a beginner of Standard SQL in Bigquery.

Here would like to keep and output **distinct** value after aggregation

```
WITH TBL_TEST AS 
(
  SELECT "AUD HKD AUD HKD" AS CURRENCY UNION ALL
  SELECT "AUD HKD HKD AUD"  UNION ALL
  SELECT "CNY HKD AUD CNY"  UNION ALL
  SELECT "AUD AUD AUD AUD" 
)
```

The expect output is below, how can it solve with ?

Appreciate each of your sincerely reply.

```
+------------------+-----------------+
|    CURRENCY      |      OUTPUT     | 
+------------------+-----------------+
| AUD HKD AUD HKD  | AUD HKD         |        
| AUD HKD HKD AUD  | AUD HKD         |    
| CNY HKD AUD CNY  | CNY HKD AUD     |
| AUD AUD AUD AUD  | AUD             |
+------------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

With the following code, you get the desired output:

```
WITH TBL_TEST AS 
(
  SELECT "AUD HKD AUD HKD" AS CURRENCY UNION ALL
  SELECT "AUD HKD HKD AUD"  UNION ALL
  SELECT "CNY HKD AUD CNY"  UNION ALL
  SELECT "AUD AUD AUD AUD" 
)

,split_in_columns as (
SELECT 
  CURRENCY, 
  currency_column 
FROM TBL_TEST, UNNEST(SPLIT(CURRENCY, " ")) currency_column)

,remove_duplicates as (
SELECT 
  DISTINCT * 
FROM split_in_columns)

SELECT 
  STRING_AGG(currency_column, " ") output 
FROM remove_duplicates 
GROUP BY CURRENCY
```

I think the most important part is the split_in_columns CTE where I'm splitting the currencies in an Array, and unnested that with the original table.

Then, I just removing duplicates and recreating the CURRENCY column as an STRING. If you want the outcome as an Array, you can simply change the `STRING_AGG` with `ARRAY_AGG`.

Comment: Yes, after split the value then I have no idea what to do next in BQ previously.
Now I know which part I miss.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select currency, 
  ( select string_agg(distinct value, ' ')
    from unnest(split(currency, ' ')) value
  ) as output
from tbl_test
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output si

[image]

Comment: Appreciate for your help. That's work!
Here will modify as temp function to use.

Comment: sure. you can wrap up this simple logic as UDF. Meantime, please accept and vote up (if not yet) the answer if it helped :o)